# Is Hibernate is used in heavy ERP solution

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, design-patterns

Is Hibernate is sufficient for handling an ERP application with 1000+ tables, Is there is any performance bottleneck occurred in any stage of the development.

If we proceed with Hibernate which design pattern we follow.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate is an ORM tool. It is supposed to map classes to tables, objects to tuples and so on. The main purpose of such a tool should be to cut down the boilerplate in accessing the database while saving, updating, deleting or fetching data from tables corresponding to an OO environment. If you have 1000+ tables in your system and they all (or in conjunctions) correspond to classes in your OO API, you should be good to go.

However, the real problem with using Hibernate with high volumes of data lies in the type of operation you want to perform. For CUD operations, hibernate is quite handy, but if you have to read data from several tables at once, you might have to apply a lot of trick with lazy loading (which for me is an overhead), otherwise it will try to load the data from entire family of classes (dependents and their dependents and so on). I found iBatis good for such a scenario (Reporting tool).
So, my answer would be unless you are going to do a lot of object persistence/ update/ delete in the object-oriented structure which is going to replicate in your database, you should not put the effort in trying to implement Hibernate.

A brief comparison of both (Hibernate and iBatis) can be found below:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192005

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077875/open-source-tools/ibatis--hibernate--and-jpa--which-is-right-for-you-.html

Comment: I don't agree with this: `read data from several tables at once, you might have to apply a lot of trick with lazy loading`. We can use projections, join fetch and other approaches for that. Just need to check generated SQL and use the most suitable approaches.

Comment: I'd agree, I should write "including but not limited to lazy loading" instead of "with lazy loading". Thanks for bringing it to attention.